# sql: order the group of records (mix of 2 columns)

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I want to order a table by 2 columns. but not simple `order by col1, col2`. Its better with example -

```
id, name, time
1, a, 1000
2, b, 950
2, c, 900
1, d, 900
```

I want this ordered as

```
id, name, time
1, a, 1000
1, d, 900
2, b, 950
2, c, 900
```

a combination of id and time order. if you see this is ordered by id (but most recent order first). and then time order within id group. or you can say order the group of records perhaps.

Quick help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
order by max(time) over (id) desc, id, time desc
```

This orders by the maximum `time` on an `id`, then by `id` (in case there are duplicates), and finally by `time` within each `id`.

Comment: need standard sql. can have joins or subqueries. but a standard sql

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
syntax to use near 'over (id) desc, id, time desc. Over gives error on mysql

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer -

`SELECT * FROM  mytable p1 
 INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(time) maxtime, id FROM mytable
            GROUP BY id) p2 
 ON p1.id = p2.id
 ORDER BY maxtime DESC, p1.id, p1.time DESC`